# Is a spatial effect a random or a fixed effect?

Tags: econometrics

Below is the definition taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_effects_model)(with some minor alterations)

> Consider the linear unobserved effects model for N
> observations and $T$ time periods: :$y_{it} = X_{it}\mathbf{\beta}+\alpha_{i}+u_{it}$ for $t=1,\dots,T$ and
> $i=1,\dots,N$
>
> Where:
>
> - $y_{it}$ is the dependent variable observed for individual $i$ at time $t$.
> - $X_{it}$ is the time-variant $1\times k$ (the number of independent variables) regressor vector.
> - $\beta$ is the $k\times 1$ matrix of parameters.
> - $\alpha_{i}$ is the *unobserved* time-invariant individual effect. For example, the innate ability for individuals or historical and institutional factors for countries.
> - $u_{it}$ is the error term.
>
> The fixed effects (FE) model allows $\displaystyle \alpha _{i}$ to be
> correlated with the regressor matrix $\displaystyle X_{it}$. Strict
> exogeneity with respect to the idiosyncratic error term $\displaystyle u_{it}$ is still required.

Firstly, how does the definition usually used in Econometrics(I don't know which is it) relates to this one?

Reading this definition, I would say that a spacial effect term would be highly correlated to $X_{it}$ and therefore it 'fitted' the definition of a fixed effect. I'm thinking for example in a situation where (innate)ability can be highly correlated to the pollution in a certain region.

However, in the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode), definition 4 of a random effect seems to also 'fit' perfectly to a spatial effect.

Maybe a spatial effect can be both... like a $\alpha_i \sim S(X_{it})$?

Comment: I've also posted it here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496618/is-a-spatial-effect-a-random-or-fixed-effect  with a focus on the general statistical context